# Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, arkit

Hi I am a 3D modeler working on an Augmented Reality project and am not experienced in developing at all. I have been testing animated models in ARKit with some success but have recently come across a build error that says:

Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code.

This is very frustrating and is not allowing me to build any of the previously working ARKit scenes that I had made. If anyone knows why this is happening I'd be very grateful to hear a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue I went to `Finder` and browsed to the project folder and then the `scnassets` folder.

I then added the `.scn` extension myself and it built.

It still had warnings about not loading the frameworks but the error went away. I think it might have something to do with `Mojave` since I have never had this issue before.

A co-worker had similar issues and we resolved it by, Source Control -> Discard all changes, clean build folder, then build but I didn't have that option.

Comment: More context would make this much more helpful, I feel.